Why doesn't sed work with my netcat input?
netcat -k -l 10080 | grep --line-buffered "GET /" \
| cut -b6- | sed "s/HTTP.*//"

It works fine if I feed it a log file but when given the real thing it won't output.
So I tried to add -u to set but it still won't work
If fed:
GET /test message :) HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: close
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/plain

It's supposed to output: test message :)
When sent through cat it works fine. But when it gets the real thing from netcat it won't work.
Thanks in advance

Why not simply netcat -k -l 10080 | sed -nu 's%^GET /\(.*\) HTTP/.*%\1%p' ?

It's the cut that is buffering your netcat output. So sed does not get it.
I suggest to replace the cut with a 2nd sed substitution as follows.
$ netcat -k -l 10080 | grep --line-buffered GET | sed -e "s/GET //" -e "s/ HTTP.*//"


You can use stdbuf to modify the buffering mode of the streams of a command (stdout in this case)
stdbuf -o0 netcat -k -l 10000 | sed 's/HTTP.*//'

